# Как исправить ошибку с wine?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, wine

Установил wine на ubuntu на виртуалке. Запускаю команду wine PROGRAM. И вот, что выходит:

```
system.reg is not a valid registry file
userdef.reg is not a valid registry file
user.reg is not a valid registry file
0009:err:environ:run_wineboot failed to start wineboot c000035a
0009:err:module:import_dll Loading library kernelbase.dll (which is needed by L"C:\\windows\\system32\\kernel32.dll") failed (error c000035a).
wine: could not load kernel32.dll, status c0000135
```

Как исправить это?

Comment: Как устанавливали? Запускаете из консоли или из графического эмулятора терминала?

Comment: Установил через терминал и запускал тоже

Comment: Но вайн надо запускать из-под иксов, в графике.

Comment: Я только начал пользоваться ubuntu, не могли бы вы пояснить как это?

Comment: повторю вопрос: как устанавливали?